# Why isn't Hosmer-Lemeshow test used for other models besides Logistic Regression?

Tags: classification, chi-squared-test, binary-data, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I've only seen the `Hosmer-Lemeshow` test used for Logistic Regression.  Why can't it be used for algorithm that produces probabilities for binary classification?

All the `Hosmer-Lemeshow` test requires probabilities and binary labels.  So, why hasn't it been used on models such as support vector machines, random forest, and any other binary classification algorithm?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180506/hosmer-lemeshow-for-correlated-data/180520#180520  for *why not use Hosmer-Lemeshow at all*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hosmer–Lemeshow_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosmer%E2%80%93Lemeshow_test) is actually applying the [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) on deciles of confidence for both binary outcomes.

As such, it is can indeed be used in any binary classifier that provides confidence.

As for why it is more common for logistic regression, I can speculate.
It seems that the test was introduced at [Applied logistic regression. D. W. Hosmer and S. Lemeshow, Wiley, New York, 1989](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.4780100718/abstract). As the book name implies, the focus is logistic regression so that is why it is used in this classifier context.

As for why it is not common when other classifier are being used, I believe it is since other measures suites more the researchers need in unsupervised learning. 
The chi-square test estimates fit and it is symmetric with respect to the deviation. In supervised learning we are usually interested in many aspects of the performance. One might want to [maximize precision while other would like to maximize recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

Comment: One might also point out that is has been re-evaluated by a group including the original authors [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0258(19970515)16:9%3C965::AID-SIM509%3E3.0.CO;2-O/abstract)

Comment: But all of the other measures of performance, such as ROC curve, F measure etc., are used for any kind of binary classification.  but Hosmer-Lemeshow seems to be ONLY used for logistic regression.

Comment: You are right. I guess that the roots are due to history and not due to statistics. The other measures are much older and therefore more common (for all classifiers).