# Improve the goodness-of-fit of a logistical regression

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit

I've been working on a data set with binary outcome. Logistic regression was used to fit the outcome with several covariates, all of which are categorical variables.

I tried to assess the goodness-of-fit of the logistic model to the data using the Pearson's chi-square and deviance statistics, however none of them showed the model fit to the data (p-values < 0.0001). I also used Hosmer and Lemeshow (HL) test, the results is similar with p-value < 0.0001. In order to improve the model's fit, I then added the interactions between the main effects into the model, after adding all possible interactions the fit didn't improve a lot and p-values are still < 0.0001.

```
Deviance and Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Statistics

Criterion   Value        DF   Value/DF  Pr > ChiSq
Deviance    29693.7476  4384    6.7732  <.0001
Pearson     31175.7340  4384    7.1113  <.0001

Number of unique profiles: 4409
```

I remember that we can always make the model fit by making it more complex but wondering how should I proceed? Does it make sense to include polynomial terms of the categorical variables? Or make the model non-linear? (I'm reluctant to do these as it would be hard to interpret the results.)

Here is a brief summary of the data I'm working on

> Number of Observations 495851
>
> Number of Events  105069

I'm also wondering if it's because the sample size is too large so that it's hard to find a relative simple more that fits to the data?

Thanks!

Comment: it may be good to take a look at this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169000/goodness-of-fit-test-in-logistic-regression-which-fit-do-we-want-to-test

Comment: @fcop I did. It didn't answer my question. Thanks.